# Calling a Rest-API using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest

I'm trying to call a rest-api in asp.net to test if people are trustworthy with paying by invoice. The problem is that i've never used any rest-api before and couldn't find a good example on how to call it in asp.net. Can someone help me?

Here are the values that the request needs.

[image]

```
/api/v1/RiskCube/claim

{
  "shopId": "20071992",
  "orderProcessId": "ref001",
  "ipAddress": null,
  "macAddress": null,
  "customerId": "cus001",
  "billingAddress": {
    "type": "Consumer",
    "businessName": null,
    "firstName": "Martin",
    "lastName": "Früh",
    "co": null,
    "street": "Funkenbüelstrasse",
    "houseNumber": "1",
    "postCode": "9243",
    "locationName": "Jonschwil",
    "country": "CH",
    "email": null,
    "phone": null,
    "dateOfBirth": null
  },
  "shippingAddress": null,
  "orderAmount": 1200
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to call a dotnet api or you are calling another API from dotnet code?

Comment: I'm trying to call another API from dotnet code

Comment: Nice. Do you have any question? Are you facing any problem?

Comment: Yes sadly i can't find any reference on how to call it exactly.

Comment: @TimSpilka Take a look at [System.Net.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @TimSpilka first, there's no thing like a REST-API. REST isn't a protocol, it's a style of building and using HTTP APIs. If you searched for `HTTP API` instead you'd have found hundreds if not thousands of articles about HttpClient.

Comment: @TimSpilka you posted a Swagger screenshot. Swagger/OpenAPI is used to define a schema on top of HTTP APIs. You can use tools to *generate* clients and DTOs from an OpenAPI description. The clients will still make plain old HTTP calls using HttpClient though. Visual Studio [has a wizard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/generating-http-api-clients-using-visual-studio-connected-services/) that will do just that. There are other code generation tools, like [Swagger Code generator](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/)

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing that up @PanagiotisKanavos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can try out using HttpClient to call another API. Ex. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0 . And you can use libraries for that like Refit https://github.com/reactiveui/refit

edit: Link in english
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the answers in the end i came out with that result.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://service-zs.riskcube.ch/api/v1/RiskCube/claim");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "X-API-KEY"); //Add a valid API Key
        if (creditReformModel != null)
        {
            string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(creditReformModel);
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(postData);
            }
        }
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I think for most people @Serhii answer is better than what i came up with.